# Declaring a disposable object: inside or outside a loop?

Tags: c#, performance, idisposable

Should I use `using` block inside a loop or outside of it? Is there any sensible performance difference? Is there any difference in the case of `Graphics` object?  While the second approach may seem better, the `while`  could be a long block and make the code less readable.

```
while (i < 100)
{
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
    {
       g.DrawImage(...);
    }
}
```

vs.

```
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
{
   while (i < 100) // a long while block
   {
       // I may use other functions such as g.DrawLine .. or g.DrawText ... 
       // Moreover while could be a long block
       g.DrawImage(...);

   }
}
```

Comment: I think 2nd one is better

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `Graphics` class but definitively performance will be better if you create one instance vs creating 100. Probably the difference won't be noticiable but no question that normally you would go for option 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, place the `using` inside the loop if you plan to use the object only once OR the object is not designed to be reused (SQLCommand class comes to mind as an example). Otherwise place it outside the loop.

In your specific case, if your intent is to draw the same image 100 times, then outside the loop is the way to go. On the other hand, if your intent is to draw 100 distinct images inside a loop, then the only way it could work would be to place the `using` inside the loop, because the `Graphics` object cannot be reused with another image.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you're using a different Bitmap for each loop, you should put the using block outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

in terms of performance outside of the while loop so you don't have to make 100 objects. It might depend how you want to manage exceptions though.

Answer (score 1):

Given the sample code, I would absolutely go for the second option and put the loop inside the using.  Far better performance that way.

If there's additional logic that is changing which bitmap you are using in the middle of the loop, you may need to consider the first option.  Just be aware that you will likely suffer a performance hit.